# Unable to start colord service under docker container

Tags: linux, docker, cups, calibration, color-profile

My goal is to use my own ICC profiles in CUPS printing system for color-corrected printing using colord but i'm unable to start colord in container under BalenaOS. Any suggestions?

**Colord version:** 1.4.3-4

**Docker:**
Version: 19.03.13-dev \ API version: 1.40 \ Go version: go1.12.17 \ OS/Arch: linux/arm64 \ Experimental: false

**Colord install command:** `sudo apt-get install colord`

---

**Colord verbose start output:**

```
#/usr/lib/colord/colord --verbose
12:02:38        Verbose debugging enabled (on console 1)
12:02:38        CdMappingDb: trying to open database '/var/lib/colord/mapping.db'
12:02:38        CdDeviceDb: trying to open database '/var/lib/colord/storage.db'
12:02:38        CdProfileDb: trying to open database '/var/lib/colord/storage.db'
12:02:38        searching for plugins in /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/colord-plugins
12:02:38        run cd_plugin_initialize on /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/colord-plugins/libcolord_sensor_sane.so
12:02:38        finished cd_plugin_initialize
12:02:38        run cd_plugin_initialize on /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/colord-plugins/libcolord_sensor_camera.so
12:02:38        finished cd_plugin_initialize
12:02:38        run cd_plugin_initialize on /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/colord-plugins/libcolord_sensor_scanner.so
12:02:38        finished cd_plugin_initialize
12:02:38        System vendor: 'Unknown', System model: 'Unknown'
12:02:38        CdMain: lost name: org.freedesktop.ColorManager
12:02:38        run cd_plugin_destroy on /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/colord-plugins/libcolord_sensor_sane.so
12:02:38        finished cd_plugin_destroy
12:02:38        run cd_plugin_destroy on /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/colord-plugins/libcolord_sensor_camera.so
12:02:38        finished cd_plugin_destroy
12:02:38        run cd_plugin_destroy on /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/colord-plugins/libcolord_sensor_scanner.so
12:02:38        finished cd_plugin_destroy
```

---

Error from colormgr command. Also other services dependent on colord are creating same or similar error output.

colormgr: `No connection to colord: Could not connect: No such file or directory`

Also start script for colord is not present in /etc/init.d folder... if it should exists.

---

### Actual problem

Colord won't start.

---

### Expecting behaviour

Colord starts and appears in running services fully accessible by colormgr in docker container.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, because I don't know colord, but, isn't the aim of Balena that you don't have to install anything at the OS level, but instead, you do everything through a docker container? It's clear from the use of `sudo` that you're not installing this in a container, so I'm left wondering what this has to do with docker and if you're even doing the right thing.

Comment: I was installing colord on device in local mode... inside running container to debug this behaviour. IMHO i dont think it depends on whether it's installed with or without sudo as long as container knows what sudo command is. (to be sure i reinstalled colord without sudo and same error/problem occurred).

Comment: Typically, you don't have sudo inside a docker container as they are all built as root by default.